# Query running drastically different through .net sql driver vs Sql Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Our application uses the .net sql driver, and the queries end up looking something like this in profiler:

```
sp_executesql N'query where @param = ?, and param2 = ?', param, param2, param3, etc
```

When copying and pasting the query from Profiler into sql server management studio, the query will run in less than a minute vs 15 - 20 minutes executing from the application.

As far as I can tell they are both using the same execution plan, so I'm not sure what would be different.

To add to the strangeness, we also have a testing sql server which is basically a copy of the production server.  In our testing environment with the same code and mostly the same data (a few days out of date from production), the query runs in less than a minute in our application as well as in sql server management studio.  Once again, profiler is capturing the exact same execution plan for all of them.

The only thing I've discovered makes the query run correctly is to run sp_updatestats on the database, which we run every morning at 5:00 am.  What's strange is by 7:00 am the query will still running slow again.  If I run sp_updatestats again, the query will finish in less than a minute.  Once again, all execution plans look the same.

I must be missing something.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked that auto create statistics and auto update statistics for the database(s) are enabled? They probably are, but worth checking.

Answer (score 1):

Does your query involve a table with an ascending datetime or datetime2 column, and one of the parameters is a datetime or datetime2 which is typically looking for a recent value?

Your comments regarding behavior after updating statistics suggests you are experiencing the problem with frequently out of date statistics that Gail Shaw describes here: http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/statistics-row-estimations-and-the-ascending-date-column/

As Gail mentions, the most straightforward resolution is a more frequent update of statistics. Ideally target those more frequent updates to the statistics that need them only-- see [Update Statistics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx).

In the case of very large tables, a filtered index might also be useful, depending on the table size and update and read patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Currently in the process of trying to upgrade my SQL Skills, so take this with a grain of salt. But perhaps this is a **Parameter Sniffing** issue?:

> Parameter sniffing is the process
>   whereby  SQL Server creates an optimal
>   plan for a stored procedure by using
>   the calling parameters that are passed
>   the first time a stored procedure is
>   executed.  By “first time”, I really
>   mean whenever SQL Server is forced  to
>   compile or recompile  a stored
>   procedures because it is not in the
>   procedure cache. Every subsequent call
>   to the same store procedure with the
>   same parameters will also get an
>   optimal plan, whereas calls with
>   different parameter values may not
>   always get an optimal plan.

-- http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/

As I said in my disclaimer, I have a lot to learn here, but if I understand this correctly if this is the case I think if you pass `OPTION RECOMPILE` to the query and the problem goes away this might have been your problem.

Comment: I'll give the recompile option a try, but the problem isn't with different sets of parameters.  In all examples, all parameters are exactly the same, they are just running differently, even though the execution plans are the same.

Comment: Yeah, the recompile options doesn't resolve the issue either, and I'm still seeing the exact same execution plan.